# Azure REST API VM LicenseType parameter

Tags: azure, rest, virtual-machine

I'm trying to get LicenseType property of running VMs, but the value is not returned as part of query.
How to get it? Is it some kind of "lazy" property?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get
I tried the standard query and with &expand option..

Really need this setting for Azure VM reporting, if they using AHUB or not.
Powershell returns this value...

Answer (score 0):

The property LicenseType is only used for images that contain the Windows operating system. In other words, we just can get the property with Azure Windows VM.
[image]

Besides, if you want to get the property with Rest API, we just need to run a standard query.

For example
[image]

Comment: I wonder, why it doesn't work for any Windows VM I'm trying to. Did the same query for Windows VM. osType: "Windows", but parameter "licenseType" doesn't returned